# Find the length of the geodesic between the points $ P1 (1,0, -1) $ and $ P2 (0, - 1,1) $ in the plane $ x + y + z $

Tags: calculus, geometry, geodesic

I am new to the study of geodesics, I would like to know if someone can give me a suggestion to find the length of the geodesic between the points $ P1 (1,0, -1) $ and $ P2 (0, - 1,1) $ in the plane $ x + y + z.$

What formulas should I apply?

How do i get started?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there a specific metric attached to this plane?  If it's just the Euclidean metric then the answer is just the straight line connecting them.

Comment: Oh, of course, thanks friend. So the solution is just to find the straight line connecting the points $ P1 $ and $ P2 $, and then calculate the distance between that straight line and the plane $ x + y + z $?

Comment: Sounds like it.  Usually the word "geodesic" is reserved for non-Euclidean spaces (e.g. finding the shortest paths between two points on a sphere).

Comment: Why would you want the distance between the line and the plane? You’re meant to find the distance between the two points, which, BTW, are given as lying on the plane in the first place.

Comment: @amd so the answer is just to calculate $ d (P1, P2)?$

Comment: @J.rafa That’s the simplest solution, but perhaps you’re meant to go the long way around—don’t assume that you know what geodesics look like and actually go through the computation of the geodesic given a metric on the plane. You know what the result should be, which will allow you to check your work.